# navigation buttonItem can not show and the navigationItem background color is not very clear

Tags: ios, objective-c

why the `navigationbar` can not show leftButton and rightButton, but if I click there, it has response. And I set the background color blue, but it looks not very clear, like something covers on the `navigationItem`.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer below brother

Answer (score 1):

Add the Button in this way.

```
    UIImage *addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height)];
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAddClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

You can change the barTintColor from storyBoard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution

I tried the solution for your question and I got it.

So you have to set for the tint color for the navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Left bar button coding

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
[leftButton setTitle:@"Left" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testDemoLeft) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
```

Right Bar Button Coding

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
[rightButton setTitle:@"Right" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RightImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //etTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testDemoRight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
```

Then adding bar buttons to navigation Item

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
```

//Button actions

```
-(void)testDemoLeft
{

}

-(void)testDemoRight
{

}
```

See the output with screenshot bellow

[image]

Comment: Have you added image for that.

Comment: Also OP want Blue color for background, the back ground you have set it already OP getting in the Output.